# Screenshot в консольном приложении

Tags: c#, консоль, screenshots

Нашёл только ответ, как сделать в приложении с **Windows Forms**, вот этот код:

```
Graphics graph = null;

var bmp = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, 
Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);

graph = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

graph.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bmp.Size);

bmp.Save("filename");
```

Но если добавить его в консольном приложении, то `Graphics`, `Bitmap`, Screenshot не воспринимаются *(подчёркиваются красной волнистой линией)*. Добавив

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Я избавился от проблем с `Graphics` и `Bitmap`, однако `Screen` во второй строчке все равно не воспринимаются программой. Как можно сделать скриншот экрана из  консольного приложения?

Comment: А туда просто передайте размеры консольного окна и все дела. Думаю вам не стоит конкретно ваш размер. Там же стандарт какой есть.

Comment: А если мне нужен весь экран, а не только консоль?

Comment: Вопрос то в другом. 
 `Как можно сделать скриншот в консольном приложении?`

Comment: я имел ввиду, что код рабочий, если использовать его с Windows Forms, а если его вставить в код консольного приложения, то он нерабочий

Comment: Если нужны прям точные размеры консольного окна, то вот свойство: `Console.WindowWidth`

Comment: Добавьте к проекту сборку System.Windows.Forms.dll.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov подход не есть хороший. Там же написано как ни как для WinForm. У Console есть свои свойства для таких манипуляций. И он сказал, что это не совсем решило проблему.

Comment: @SeeSharp - У консоли нет возможности сделать скриншот экрана. Использование графической библиотеки - самое то. Он открыл пространство имен, но не добавил сборку.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да, хорошо... Я только что добавил сборку, и у меня в точности наоборот. `Screen` видит, а `Bitmap` нет

Comment: Эх, пришлось в поисковик лезть... Нужна сборка System.Drawing.dll.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov скриншот приобретает не самый лучший вид. В метод `CopyFromScreen` начальные координаты - 0,0. Поэтому выходит не скрин консоли, а скрин угла экрана с такими же размерами как у консоли

Comment: Я использовал код из вопроса, добавив сборки System.Windows.Forms и System.Drawing, сохранив в png и все вышло нормально. Вышел скрин всего экрана, как и требовалось. Спасибо.

Comment: Как?? Выложите в ответ ваш код

Comment: Почему вы в _вопрос_ не поместили важную информацию: что вызываете этот код из метода `Screen()`? Но зачем-то задали вопрос в _ответе_.

Comment: Не стоит забывать, что нужно подключить соответствующие using в references

Answer (score 3):

Итак, решение было таковым:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace Screenshot
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Graphics graph = null;

            var bmp = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
            Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);

            graph = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

            graph.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bmp.Size);

            bmp.Save("filename.png");
        }
    }
}
```

`Screen` находился в пространстве имен  `System.Windows.Forms`

`Bitmap` и `Graphics` - в `System.Drawing`. И вот так у меня вышел скриншот с полным захватом всего экрана.

Comment: Навести мышку на подчеркнутую ошибку не судьба?

Comment: "Class1.Screen() является метод, который недопустим в данном контексте" в обеих случаях

Comment: всё, я просто по глупости назвал метод `Screen`, нужно было изменить его название

Comment: Да, нужно или название метода изменить, или полностью указать пространство имен у класса Screen. Ведь имя метода не всегда можно поменять (оно может быть жестко задано интерфейсом).

Comment: Не стоит задавать вопрос в ответе. Его стоит задать или отдельно, или уточнить в комментариях.